# Multidimentions array asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

In php I could do this

```
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$_SESSION['details']=$result;
```

and Access it like this

```
$_SESSION['details']['name'];
```

How do you do this in ASP.NET CORE if you have something like this

```
 var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == model.Username && u.Password==password);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your above code will return whatever you have set up in your `Startup.cs` class's `ConfigureServices` method.  In my case I have done the following:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AlmanacDb, int>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

So your above code:

```
var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == model.Username && u.Password == password);
```

Would technically return an `ApplicationUser` object.  This is not per-say multi-dimensional object but it can have child objects which you could access properties like the following:

```
string UsersName = user.UserName;
```

A more "multi-dimensional" property would be something like the following:

```
var SomeClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClaimType == "SomeClaimType");
```

Which I suppose is similar to what you are used to of:

```
user[Claims][SomeClaimType];
```

Hope that helps.